# ReOrder a List to one after another

Tags: java, list, optimization, collections

I have a list that has three different types  They are added to a List as groups and not one by one.

These items are added to a list 5 at a time  and look like this:
(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3)

Now I want to reorder the list so it looks like this:
(1,2,3,1,2,3....)

How can I optimize this process?

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
     {
            //Reorder the list here
     }
```

Comment: Initial list a. Create another list b where b[i] = a[i/types], b[i+1] = a[(i+1)/types+n], b[i+2]=a[(i+2)/types+2n]...types=3, n=5 and i goes as 0,types,2*types, 3*types...

Comment: Well, what have you tried so far?  What are your actual items?  Can you change generation to match what you want?  If these are integers, I'd probably just reduce to a set of distinct values and iterate over the resulting list a number of times.  What happens if the original data is otherwise out of order (`1, 1, 3, 3, 2, 2`)?  What if there are different numbers of elements per group?

Comment: @wxyz - I believe the OP wants to re-order the "same " list

Comment: You could convert the list to a set.. Sort the set.. Start from the first element of the set..Then based on the "frequency" of the integer (got from the list), add the element "n" number of times to a new/old list...

Comment: To me that does not feel like an _order_. What do you want to do with the items afterwards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as all of your groups are of equal size you can use one of these aproaches:

```
import java.util.AbstractList;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Sorting {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3);
        System.out.println("Input: " + list);
        System.out.println("Solution1 (regroup): " + regroup(list, 3));
        System.out.println("Solution2 (regroup2): " + regroup2(list, 5));
        System.out.println("Solution3 (groupSize constructor): " + new GroupedList<Integer>(list, 5));
        System.out.println("Solution3 (typeCount constructor): " + new GroupedList<Integer>(3, list));
        System.out.println("Demonstration of Solution3 emptyList constructor for groupSize 5");
        final GroupedList<Integer> groupedList = new GroupedList<Integer>(5);
        final List<List<Integer>> oneOfEachType = groupedList.getOneOfEachType();
        System.out.println("Ungrouped: " + groupedList);
        System.out.println("Grouped:" + oneOfEachType);
        // While addAll is shorter code, add also works
        groupedList.addAll(Arrays.asList(11, 12, 13, 14, 15));
        groupedList.addAll(Arrays.asList(21, 22, 23, 24, 25));
        groupedList.add(31);
        groupedList.add(32);
        groupedList.add(33);
        groupedList.add(34);
        groupedList.add(35);
        System.out.println("After adding 3 groups");
        System.out.println("Ungrouped: " + groupedList);
        System.out.println("Grouped:" + oneOfEachType);
        groupedList.addAll(Arrays.asList(41, 42, 43, 44, 45));
        System.out.println("After adding 4th group");
        System.out.println("Ungrouped: " + groupedList);
        System.out.println("Grouped:" + oneOfEachType);
    }

    /**
     * Solution one: returns the reordered list, if you know how many different types are to be handled
     *
     * @param list
     *         input list with equally-sized groups of the same type following each other
     * @param typeCount
     *         count of equally sized groups are in {@code list}
     * @param <T>
     *         type of elements in {@code list}
     * @return new {@link java.util.ArrayList} consisting of the same elements as in {@code list} in the desired order.
     */
    private static <T> List<T> regroup(final List<T> list, final int typeCount) {
        final int groupSize = list.size() / typeCount;
        final ArrayList<T> result = new ArrayList<T>(list.size());
        for (int i = 0; i < groupSize; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < typeCount; j++) {
                result.add(list.get(i + j * groupSize));
            }
        }
        return result;
    }


    /**
     * Solution two: returns the reordered list, if you know how many items of each type are added
     *
     * @param list
     *         input list with equally-sized groups of the same type following each other
     * @param groupSize
     *         size of one of the equally sized groups in {@code list}
     * @param <T>
     *         type of elements in {@code list}
     * @return new {@link java.util.ArrayList} consisting of the same elements as in {@code list} in the desired order.
     */
    private static <T> List<T> regroup2(final List<T> list, final int groupSize) {
        final ArrayList<T> result = new ArrayList<T>(list.size());
        for (int i = 0; i < groupSize; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; i + j * groupSize < list.size(); j++) {
                result.add(list.get(i + j * groupSize));
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Solution three: wrapper class around the original list. This solution reflects changes to the original list
     * immediately and can be used to change the original list if desired
     *
     * @param <T>
     *         type of elements in this list
     */
    public static class GroupedList<T> extends AbstractList<T> {

        private final List<T> list;
        private final int     groupSize;

        /**
         * Empty list, than can be filled with groups of {@code groupSize} elements one group after another.
         */
        public GroupedList(final int groupSize) {
            this.list = new ArrayList<T>();
            this.groupSize = groupSize;
        }

        /**
         * Backed by a list with same-typed groups consisting each of {@code groupSize} elements
         */
        public GroupedList(final List<T> list, final int groupSize) {
            this.list = list;
            this.groupSize = groupSize;
        }


        /**
         * Backed by a list with {@code typeCount} same-typed groups consisting each of the same number of elements
         */
        public GroupedList(final int typeCount, final List<T> list) {
            this.list = list;
            this.groupSize = list.size() / typeCount;
        }

        /**
         * Number of items of the same type. You need to add this many elements at once.
         */
        public int getGroupSize() {
            return groupSize;
        }

        /**
         * Number of different types in each sub-sequence.
         */
        public int getTypeCount() {
            return list.size() / groupSize;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean add(T t) {
            return list.add(t);
        }

        @Override
        public T get(int index) {
            final int realIndex = getRealIndex(index);
            return list.get(realIndex);
        }

        @Override
        public T set(int index, T element) {
            final int realIndex = getRealIndex(index);
            if (realIndex < list.size()) {
                return list.set(realIndex, element);
            } else {
                throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Adding to this List-implementation is not possible");
            }
        }

        /**
         * Translate reordered index to index of underlying list
         */
        private int getRealIndex(int index) {
            final int typeCount = getTypeCount();
            if (typeCount * groupSize != list.size()) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("There is an incomplete group. Can't establish list order.");
            }
            final int offsetInGroup = index / typeCount;
            final int groupStart = (index % typeCount) * groupSize;
            return offsetInGroup + groupStart;
        }

        @Override
        public int size() {
            return list.size();
        }

        /**
         * Produce a list of the lists generated by {@link #getOneOfEachType(int)}. The generated list is read-only
         * while the contained lists are writable. Size of this list will always be the same as {@link #getGroupSize()}.
         */
        public List<List<T>> getOneOfEachType() {
            return new AbstractList<List<T>>() {
                @Override
                public List<T> get(int index) {
                    return getOneOfEachType(index);
                }

                @Override
                public int size() {
                    return groupSize;
                }
            };
        }

        /**
         * Get the {@code groupNumber}-th list consisting of on element of each type. You can replace elements of this
         * list and as elements are added to {@link tc.vom.test.with.deps.Sorting.GroupedList} elements will also be
         * visible through the returned list.
         */
        public List<T> getOneOfEachType(final int groupNumber) {
            return new AbstractList<T>() {

                @Override
                public T get(int index) {
                    return list.get(getRealIndex(index));
                }

                @Override
                public T set(int index, T element) {
                    return list.set(getRealIndex(index), element);
                }

                private int getRealIndex(int index) {
                    final int typeCount = getTypeCount();
                    if (index >= typeCount) {
                        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
                    }
                    if (typeCount * groupSize != list.size()) {
                        throw new IllegalStateException("There is an incomplete group. Can't establish list order.");
                    }
                    return index * groupSize + groupNumber;
                }

                @Override
                public int size() {
                    return getTypeCount();
                }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

With `regroup` you need to know how many types there are with `regroup2` you need to now how many of the same type are inserted.

With `GroupedList` you can create a wrapper around an existing `List`. You can iterate over `GroupedList` in the desired order and it will work as long as the number of elements in the original `List` does not change during iteration. You can also use `getOneOfEachType()` to itereate over individual sub-groups without having to utilize an external counter.
I implemented only `add(T)` and not `add(int,T)` as shifting the virtual order is a bit tricky (but can be done). Abstract List uses `add(T)` to implement `addAll(Collection<T>)` so this also works.
If you don't need to add to the `List` after wrapping my [previous implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/21967244/3) could be a bit faster as the typeCount is fixed. The `getOneOfEachType`-function can easily be adopted to the old implementation by replacing `getTypeCount()` with `typeCount`.

Both functions and the `GroupedList` only work if the groups are of equal size.

Comment: Your code seems correct but there is another approach. Since "...items are added to a list 5 at a time" you could use the same indexing approach to insert them to the proper location to the list **as they are added to the list**.This would be more efficient IMHO than iterating over the final list and populating *another* result list. But +1 from me

Comment: @Jim changed my `GroupedList` so you can use `add(T)` and `addAll(Collection)` on it. However without previously knowing how many groups there will be, it is tricky to directly store items in the desired order without constantly shifting the old values arround, which seems a bit inperformant to me.

Comment: You are right that it would be best if the size were know beforehand.But on the other hand the OP does not really say what is the problem he is trying to solve.Perhaps he is trying to solve the wrong problem to begin with

Comment: @Jim as hey accepted the answer at least the problem was solveable. As I assume that something will be working with the groups consisting of one element from each of the original groups I added two getOneOfEachType functions. They feel a bit more Java than the idea of itterating over the resulting list with a counter to tell when you reach a new group.